# GetChildCount of GridView only counts visible children

Tags: android

How to count all elements in gridview. For example, I have a gridview with 20 textview inside. When launch program, we only can see, for example 10 (because small screen). In this case, if I call the function:

```
System.out.print(gridview.getChildCount());
```

It only return 10, not 20. How to get all 20 children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, I have a gridview with 20 textview inside

No, you have a `GridView` with an `Adapter` containing 20 items. You are not in control over how many widgets get created by `GridView` and the `Adapter` to handle those items.

> How to get all 20 children?

There are only 10 children, in your case.

If you want to know how many items there are in the `Adapter`, call `getCount()` on the `Adapter`.

However, `GridView`, with a well-written `Adapter`, will recycle views, so the number of views will be less than the number of items in the `Adapter`.